# Suppress context menu in AxWebBrowser object -- timing issue?

Tags: c#, debugging, event-handling

I am using an EventHandler to suppress a context menu on an AxWebBrowser.  I am using the code below:

```
public class HtmlEditor : System.Windows.Forms.UserControl
{
    ...
    ...
    private AxSHDocVw.AxWebBrowser axWebBrowser1;
    ...
    ...
    public HtmlEditor()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        axWebBrowser1.DocumentComplete +=new AxSHDocVw.DWebBrowserEvents2_DocumentCompleteEventHandler(axWebBrowser1_DocumentComplete);
        axWebBrowser1.Navigate("about:blank");
        axWebBrowser1.BeforeNavigate2 +=new AxSHDocVw.DWebBrowserEvents2_BeforeNavigate2EventHandler(axWebBrowser1_BeforeNavigate2);
        mshtml.HTMLDocumentClass doc = (mshtml.HTMLDocumentClass)this.axWebBrowser1.Document;///stop here
        doc.designMode = "On";  // This turns the control into an editor ///stop here
        ((mshtml.HTMLDocumentEvents2_Event)this.axWebBrowser1.Document).oncontextmenu += new mshtml.HTMLDocumentEvents2_oncontextmenuEventHandler(HtmlEditor_oncontextmenu); //suppress context menu ///stop here
        Dirty = false;///stop here
    }

    private bool HtmlEditor_oncontextmenu(mshtml.IHTMLEventObj e)
    {
        return false;
    }
    ...
    ...
}
```

There are four lines with the comment "///stop here".  If I set a breakpoint at any one of those lines, run the app, then continue after I stop at that line, then the context menu does not appear when I right-click the control.  However, if I put a breakpoint anywhere else and do the same, the context menu appears.  Additionally, if I run the app with no breakpoints, the context menu appears.

I have also tried to assign the EventHandler in a separate method, called long after everything above is done executing, but again, the context menu appears.

Anyone have an idea how I can figure out my problem?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the WinForms [WebBrowser control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752040.aspx) and set its [IsWebBrowserContextMenuEnabled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.iswebbrowsercontextmenuenabled.aspx) property to false.

You can use its Document.DomDocument to get the raw MSHTML HTMLDocument object.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I unfortunately can't change the control type to WebBrowser.

Comment: Since the AxWebBrowser isn't exposed by the control, why can't you change it to WebBrowser?

Comment: I believe the only reason is that the WebBrowser.Document needs to be editable. AxWebBrowser makes it easy to edit the Document.  I'm sure a Document in WebBrowser could be made editable (found part of a solution at http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/Vsexpressvcs/thread/7e6444bd-8dbc-489b-8f70-622aef381741), but I am going to have to do a full review to make sure changing to WebBrowser doesn't break any other code.